# Does there exist a simple group with three or more subgroups?

Tags: group-theory

I was wondering if the word normal is redundant in the definition of a simple group.

I strongly feel that there must be a simple group with at least three subgroups. However, I'm unable to find any.

Any help?

Comment: What simple groups do you know?

Comment: The alternating groups are simple. Also, every permutation of 3 elements generates a subgroup of order 3. So, if you take the alternating group $A_4$ and 3 subgroups of this form, that works as an example.

Comment: **Every** group of composite order has nontrivial subgroups, namely, cyclic subgroups.

Comment: @ZoeAllen $A_4$ is not simple.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The alternating group $A_n$ is simple for $n\geq 5$. And it is of order $n!/2$. This means that given any set of primes $p_1,\ldots,p_m$ there will be $n$ such that each $p_i$ divides the order of $A_n$, which means that the number of subgroups of $A_n$ grows to infinity with $n$.